# Is there any linux media service software that can support *.sup inside mkv file and transcode for DLNA protocol?

Tags: linux, media-player, media-converter

I have an LG WebOS TV that can only support `*.srt` subtitles and a Linux home server.

I did a lot of search, but I can not find any media service software that supports `*.sup` subtitles (HDMV PGS) **inside** mkv files.

I tried plex, jellyfin, emby, kodi and minidlna. Some of them can transcode video and sound that my TV not supported, but none of them can transcode the sup subtitle.